# How to use validations in openerp 6.1

Tags: odoo

Hi Everyone we have a problem and i am new to openerp 6.1 its like

We are testing openerp so we are going with pre installed modules and is not using our own modules what we are looking to test leave part here when someone applies for the leave it should have this provision that for particular leave there should be a minimum days and maximum days (i know its not allocation request) we are talking about the leave form where its ask what kind of leave lets say we are taking a Sick Leave more than 2 days we shall be able to upload some doctor prescription and same would be for another leaves

How we can implement those validations confirming

Saransh

Answer (score 0):

Well, You just need module customization, This is  your specific requirement. This is not question, rather this is requirement, please talk to some OpenERP Vendors.

Thank You

Comment: i said that needs Customization. you need to spent money.